# How can I get a custom attribute in my custom shipping carrier file

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-attributes, shipping-address

I have created a custom attribute "**test**" in my customer address follwing the
[magento docs add new  feild in shipping address](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)

Now this attribute is required in my custom shipping method for rate calculation.
I can see the custom attribute is sent through ajax param in **estimate-shipping-method** ajax call.

My test field n checkout address
[image]

The custom attribute being sent in the ajax request
[image]

But I'm not getting this custom attribute in the **estimateByAddress** define in class

> Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement
> on printing the getCustomAttributes()

it's returning null.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste your code here so we can understand what exactly went wronng.

Comment: I've added the image for reference. As I'm trying to get the attribute in the magento class Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement.